# can't get snipMate to work with gvim on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gvim

I start a new `test.html` type `html` and pres  but nothing happens.

Yet when `:scriptnames` does show `snipMate.vim`

below is the output for `:scriptnames`

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim72/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim72/filetype.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim72/menu.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim72/autoload/paste.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/syntax.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/synload.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/syncolor.vim
 10: /home/bhaarat/.vimrc
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim72/colors/darkblue.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/detectindent.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/matchparen.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/snipMate.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/gvimrc
```

what could I be doing wrong?? I'm feeling very frustrated being stuck on this.

`vimrc` file contains followin:

```
runtime! debian.vim

:filetype plugin on
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [an issue with snipMate and gvim](http://code.google.com/p/snipmate/issues/detail?id=66). I had the same problem once. To fix:

```
source ~/.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is something wrong with your snipMate installation.  (I don't normally use snipMate, but I installed it in its own directory to answer another question about it on SU.)  When I open a `test.html` and type `html<tab>`, I get the expected response, but also, when I then execute `:scriptnames`, I see not only `.../plugin/snipMate.vim` but `.../after/plugin/snipMate.vim`, `.../ftplugin/html_snip_helper.vim` and `.../autoload/snipMate.vim` as well.  In particular, the mappings are defined in `.../after/plugin/snipMate.vim`, which I did not see in your list.

Did snipMate come with your Debian vim package, or did you install snipMate yourself?